# Complete stack trace with TraceKit javascript library

Tags: javascript, tracekit

I'm trying out [TraceKit](https://github.com/occ/TraceKit) to automatically report Javascript errors to the server. It works as it should, with the exception of the stack trace. It only contains a single element:

```
TraceKit.report.subscribe(function(stackInfo) { alert(stackInfo.stack.length);});

function foo() {
   bar();
}

function bar() {                                                
   throw "oops";
}

foo();
```

The alert shows '1'. I've also created [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aleksabl/nMmTm/) with the same code;

Why don't I get the complete stack trace? I've tested with both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now, you'll want to change `throw "oops";` to `throw new Error("oops");` you should then get a full stack trace.

In the future, TraceKit can fix this by re-throwing an error and fixing the stack trace accordingly. This jsfiddle shows re-throwing to get a real stack trace: http://jsfiddle.net/DevinRhode2/dAYmJ/1/

The code there is:

```
try {
  function foo() {
     bar();
  }

  function bar() {                                                
     throw "oops";
  }

  foo();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e, e.message, e.stack); //oops undefined undefined 
  try {
    throw new Error(e);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(
      e,       e.message, e.stack);/*
      Error {} "oops"     "Error: oops
        at file://localhost/Users/devinrhode2/Desktop/test.html:23:13"
    */
  }
}​​​​​​​
```

Other discussion on TraceKit on github here: https://github.com/occ/TraceKit/issues/23

Thanks Alex for bringing this up!